# NDB querying results that start with a string

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Working with Google App Engine's NDB, I'm looking to query for all items that start with a user-inputted string.
Example:

```
abc_123
abcdefg
123abc
```

Querying for "abc" should return abc_123, abcdefg (however, not 123abc as it doesn't
    start with "abc")

I previously used the code below for a similar but different purpose:

```
q = q.filter(order._properties[kw].IN(values_list))
```

which filtered for all values in values_list that were in kw, I am now looking to filter for all values that start with a string that are in kw.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
Kind.query(ndb.AND(Kind.property >= "abc", Kind.property <= "abcz"))
```

Comment: need something like this, using z is not guarantee to get all the prefix
Kind.query(ndb.AND(Kind.property >= prefix, Kind.property <= prefix + u'\ufffd'))