# Cloud Datastore 'like' query

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, gql

I've an entity in Google Cloud Datastore. One of the properties is array of strings. For example:

**property**: skills

**Entity 1:**
value: `["mysql","sqlserver","postgresql","sqllite","sql-server-2008","sql"]`

**Entity 2:**
value: `["css","css3"]`

Now, I need to query for those entities that contain array elements `css*`

In typical SQL, it'll be `select * from kindName where skills like 'css%'`

I tried `select * from kindName where skills = 'css'`, which works fine but how can I get entities that have `css*` elements similar to the SQL query?

Or

What's the best way to model the data for this?

Comment: Make sure to write `css` every time `css3` is used? Or try queries by prefix, .e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702958/ndb-querying-results-that-start-with-a-string

Answer (score 2):

You can do inequality range checks on a single indexed property as given in the example below. Range checks on strings are essentially how you can perform prefix searching on strings.

`SELECT * from yourKind WHERE skills >= "css" AND skills < "cst"`

As an example, here is the query performed on some sample data I created in the UI Console for Cloud Datastore:

[image: Example performed in the Google Cloud Datastore's console]